# Como ejecutar un bash script desde HTML / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, web, bash

Desde hace tiempo he estado probando el host gratuito 260mb para páginas web.
La verdad está bastante bien, pero quería intentar ejecutar un código bash que carga la página web (junto con otros archivos de NodeJS). Sin embargo he intentando cambiar el HTACCESS y otros métodos, pero no funcionan.

¿Alguien sabe que hacer?¿Hay algún método o solución?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: La respuesta a la pregunta es **No se puede**. Recuerda que el HTML y javascript se ejecutan en el cliente, es decir, regularmente en un navegador que se ejecuta en la PC, celular o lo que sea que se haya conectado al servidor. Si tienes un script o agente en el servidor web que lo invoque, entonces si podrías lanzarlo, con un GET o POST, desde el cliente, haciendo la petición correspondiente.